# How to make an Interpreter "representation independent with respect to closures" (Racket)

Tags: functional-programming, closures, racket, interpreter

I have to make two interpreters (one using a functional representation of closures, and another using a data-structural representation of closures). For now we'll just work in the fn (or functional representation). So far I have something like the following as a starting point:

```
(define val-of-fn
  (lambda (exp env)
    (match exp
      [(? number?) exp]
      [(? symbol?) (apply-env env exp)]
      [`(lambda(,x),body) (lambda (v) (val-of-fn body (extend-env x v env)))]
      [`(,rator ,rand) ((val-of-fn rator env)(val-of-fn rand env))])))

(define apply-env
  (lambda (env x)
      (env x)))

(define empty-env
  (lambda ()
    (lambda (y)
      (error "Unbound identifier: ~s" y))))

(define extend-env
  (lambda (x a env)
    (lambda (y) (if (eqv? x y) a (apply-env env y)))))
```

I also need to make two helper functions per data representation. apply-closure-fn, closure-fn, apply-closure-ds, and closure-ds. But I don't know where to go from here. What would these closure functions do? And how do they work in the function I have thus far?

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(val-of-fn '(lambda (x) (+ x 1) initial-env)` will evaluate to a closure represented what-you-return-for-closures in val-of-fn. Let's call the type Closure. The expression `(val-of-fn (f 42) an-env)` where f is bound to a Closure must apply the closure to a value. I.e. `(val-of-fn (f 42) an-env) = (apply-closure-ds (env 'f) an-env)`. When you represent Closure as a standard a standard Racket closure, then `apply-closure-ds` is simply good old `apply`. When you represent closures in a different way, you need to do more work.

You presumably have specification of what closure-fn a friends should do? What is it?